# PHP - User stored in Session during a Database editing

Tags: php, database, oop, session

I have a system that represents users as object. These object are initialized by reading in a database. Once the users (or objects) are created I store them in a session in order to navigate through pages without re-initiate the users from the database.

Suppose that an admin changes (let say) the users' permissions. From the edit until the session expires, a user could have higher (or lower) permissions than those declared by the admin.

How can I handle this kind of situation? Suppose I have a sessions that expires after hours or more. Should I send a request to database every *n* minutes to update the user objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it in my applications is a check on every page load.

So, permissions might be stored in a session, but you can always update those.

Let's say someone logs in and their permissions are set to full.

If you're checking on every page load and updating their session, someone can update their permissions at any time and their object will have the new permissions reflected every time they perform an action.

It doesn't matter much if they're just reading a page, but when they try to do something: submit a form, go back to home, visit a new page, or whatever, then their permissions will get updated.

Comment: But with this solution sessions are useless in order to retrieve user objects. I could retrieve users directly from the database on every page load. What if admin changes the usernames? I should update every attribute of the user every time because I don't know what an admin coul change.

Comment: If you're storing, at least, the ID of the user in the database, you can do a lookup based on that. The ID of a user is not likely to change. But yeah, it takes next to no time at all to retrieve a user's details from the database so it's worth refreshing it on every page action if you've got a permissions system in place.